# Python: Scraping the most common words on the front page of the New York Times

Tags: python, web-scraping, words

I can't seem to get my code to run.  I haven't seen anyone with the same error code.  Calling people smarter than me, any ideas?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from collections import Counter
from string import punctuation

r = requests.get("https://www.nytimes.com/?mcubz=0")

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")

text = (''.join(s.findAll(text=True))for s in soup.findAll('p'))

c = Counter((x.rstrip(punctuation).lower() for y in text for x in y.split()))

print (c.most_common())
```

Here is my error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ScrapeNews.py", line 19, in <module>
    print (c)
  File "C:\Users\Antra\Desktop\Python\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2014' in position 218: character maps to <undefined>
```

I'm flummoxed.

Comment: Why is the traceback quoting lines that don't exist in your program?

Comment: The code you posted has 14 lines. The error happens in line 19 in the function call ``print (c)`` - but ``print (c)`` is not part of the code you posted. Something here is off. We're flummoxed.

Comment: Relax your parser to html. `BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html")`